# Errors after deploying on 000webhost laravel and react

Tags: php, laravel

I had a project with **laravel** and **react** and after deploying it on **000webhost** and doing all the settings and cleaning the cache it returns these errors:

[image]

I ran all the cleaning commands on laravel.

please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO.  [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) - edit your question and post the key parts of your error as *text*.

Answer (score 0):

upload the local project again on 000webhost